# munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer in a merge sort

Tags: c, sorting, malloc, heap-memory, overflow

I implemented a merge sort with C. The source code is following.

test.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int* space;

void merge(int list[], int start, int mid, int end);
void merge_sort(int list[], int start, int end);

int main(void)
{
    int n, i;

    scanf("%d", &n);

    int* list = malloc(n);
    space = malloc(n);

    for (i = 0;i < n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &list[i]);
    }

    merge_sort(list, 0, n - 1);

    for (i = 0;i < n;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", list[i]);
    }

    free(list);
    free(space);
}

void merge(int list[], int start, int mid, int end)
{
    int i, j, k, c;
    i = start;
    j = mid + 1;
    k = start;

    while (i <= mid && j <= end)
    {
        if (list[i] < list[j])
        {
            space[k++] = list[i++];
        }
        else
        {
            space[k++] = list[j++];
        }
    }

    if (i > mid)
    {
        for (c = j;c <= end;c++)
        {
            space[k++] = list[c];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (c = i;c <= mid;c++)
        {
            space[k++] = list[c];
        }
    }

    for (c = start;c <= end;c++)
    {
        list[c] = space[c];
    }
}

void merge_sort(int list[], int start, int end)
{
    if (start < end)
    {
        int mid = (start + end) / 2;
        merge_sort(list, start, mid);
        merge_sort(list, mid + 1, end);
        merge(list, start, mid, end);
    }
}
```

And, I compiled it with gcc applying security options like following.

```
gcc test.c -o test -fPIE -no-pie -fno-stack-protector
```

These options disable pie and canary.

When I gave following inputs to this program, I met to a runtime error.

```
munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer
zsh: IOT instruction  ./test
```

inputs

```
10
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
```

To find the reason, I dumped some values like space and list. There was some odd values in space. space[8] was 1667330163, space[9] was 1563974501. But other values like ones in which space, is normal. I had tried to find heap overflows simillar to [malloc(): corrupted top size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56317418/malloc-corrupted-top-size), but I couldn't. What happend in this program? I really want to know.

Comment: The `malloc` function allocates a chunk of ***bytes***, not elements. So `malloc(n)` will allocate `n` bytes, not `n` integer elements.

Comment: Oh thanks! I modified n in malloc to n*sizeof(int) and it works. I was so stupid.

Comment: You can possibly add ` -fsanitize=address,undefined` to your compile command line to help find memory corruption issues like this. I don't know if the other flags you are using conflict with AddressSanitizer so you may need to juggle things around a bit when you;re trying to track a problem down.